# How does FluentNHibernate know which row to access?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

There is no issue; I'm just curious as to how FluentNHibernate/NHibernate  knows which rows to access.

In the following pseudocode, I have these entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}   

public class Friend
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual String FunnyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

with this one-to-many relationship:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    // One user has many friends
    HasMany(x => x.Friends).KeyColumn("UserId")...
}    

public class FriendMap : ClassMap<Friend>
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.User, "UserId")... 
}
```

If I run the following code to establish the two-way relationship:

```
var user = new User().Friends.AddRange( /* 5 friends */ );
/* 5 friends */.ForEach(friend => friend.User = user);
```

and then set:

```
user[2].FunnyProperty = "a magic string";
```

then, in a visual database explorer tool, I see the table **Users** as:

---

```
Id 
--------------------------------------
63
--------------------------------------
```

---

and the table **Friends** as:

---

```
Id | UserId | FunnyProperty
--------------------------------------
24 |   63   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
25 |   63   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
26 |   63   | a magic string
--------------------------------------
27 |   63   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
28 |   63   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
```

---

How does FluentNHibernate/NHibernate "remember" *id 26* as the 3rd `Friend` object in `user.Friends`? Say you commit the transaction, begin another transaction elsewhere, and retrieve the same `user.Friends[2]`. How does FluentNHibernate/NHibernate know to access the row with *id 26*?

Especially when when you have a **Friends** table with many different **Users** floating about, like below, how does FluentNHibernate/NHibernate "remember" which row to access ?:

---

```
Id | UserId | FunnyProperty
--------------------------------------
24 |   24   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
25 |   89   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
26 |   66   | a magic string
--------------------------------------
27 |   12   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
28 |   66   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
28 |   89   |    (null)
--------------------------------------
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Friends table contains the property UserId which is the referenence to friends. Fluent NHibernatie reads you mapping where you have defined this.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an index column in the Friends table.